# Regular expression with two underlines

Tags: python, regex

```
"music_neu_3, music_pos_76, books_neg_104"
```

How could I use regular expression in Python to find such pattern that word + underline + word + underline + number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a pattern that expresses just that:

```
[a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+_\d+
```

`\w` cannot be used here as it includes letters *and* underscores, so an explicit sequence of letters is used instead. `\d` matches digits.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+_\d+', "music_neu_3, music_pos_76, books_neg_104")
['music_neu_3', 'music_pos_76', 'books_neg_104']
```

Comment: This also matches cases without underlines, like "foo23", doesn't it?